# Angular router navigate doesn't load page when query parameters change

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a component that display the result of an API query. I want to add a dropdown box so the list can be filtered but I can't seem to get the page to reload when the url query parameters change.

```
<div>
  <H2>Products</H2>
  <form>
    Filter By Manufacturer
    <select (change)="onManufacturerChange($event.target.value)">
      <option value="">All</option>
      <option [value]="m" *ngFor="let m of manufacturers">{{m}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let p of products"><B>{{p.manufacturer}}</B> - {{p.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the Typescript

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  public products: Array<object> = [];
  public manufacturers: any = [];
  public manufacturer: string = "";
  public search: string = "";

  constructor(private _assetService: AssetService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
      if('manufacturer' in params){
        this.manufacturer = params.manufacturer;
      }
      if('search' in params){
        this.search = params.search;
      }
    })

    this._assetService.getManufacturers().subscribe(data => {
      this.manufacturers = data;
    })

    this.loadProducts(); 
  }

  loadProducts(){
      this._assetService.getProducts(this.manufacturer,this.search).subscribe((data: ProductListResult) => {
      this.products = data.products;
    }) 
  }

  onManufacturerChange(newValue){
    this.router.navigate(['/products'], {queryParams: {manufacturer: newValue}});
  }
}
```

When I change the item selected in the drop down box the URL displayed in the browser changes but the page does not reload. If I refresh the browser manually with the desired URL the correct output is shown. If I change the  path in route.navigate to a totally different route that works correctly. If I add a call to `loadProducts()` after router navigate some it reloads the page but one selection out of phase.

Everything I've read says that if the array referenced in ngFor changes it should automagically update the DOM but I can't seem to trigger it. Do I need to call some sort of refresh or invalidate routine to update the DOM? Do I need to set something in the router to recognize changes to the query parameters? Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: https://medium.com/@kevinkreuzer/refresh-current-route-in-angular-512a19d58f6e

Comment: try to update your `queryParams` like this `history.replaceState(null, null, 'URL' + '?id=' + id + '&role=' + role)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no elegant way to get Angular to reload the page when the query parameters change.

The error in my code is that *loadProducts()* uses this.manufacturer so I need to set that in *onManufacturerChange()*. It doesn't reload the page but it does reload the data and update the DOM.

Then I need to create an *updateRoute()* function that is called after subscribe has loaded the data from the api. The Back and Forward buttons in the browser still don't work (it steps through the URLs but doesn't update the display) but the URL and the display otherwise stay in sync. Close enough for now.

```
  loadProducts() {
    this._assetService.getProducts(this.manufacturer,this.search).subscribe((data: ProductListResult) => {
      this.products = data.products;
      this.updateRoute();
    })
  }

  onManufacturerChange(newValue){
    this.manufacturer = newValue;
    this.loadProducts();
  }

  updateRoute( ){
    var queryParams = {};
    if (this.manufacturer!= "" ){queryParams['manufacturer'] = this.manufacturer;}
    if (this.search!= "" ){queryParams['manufacturer'] = this.search;}
    this.router.navigate(['/products'], {queryParams: queryParams});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As of **Angular v5** there is now an option on the `Router` class [onSameUrlNavigation](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#onSameUrlNavigation)

> How to handle a navigation request to the current URL. One of:
>
> - 'ignore' : The router ignores the request.
> - 'reload' : The router reloads the URL. Use to implement a "refresh" feature.

In the main app routing file, set the value to `'reload'`:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(
  routes,
  { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to update your method **onManufacturerChange** by adding one extra param

**relativeTo**

```
onManufacturerChange(newValue){
    this.router.navigate(['/products'], {queryParams: {manufacturer: newValue},relativeTo : this.route});
  }
```

here **this.route** will be instance of **ActivatedRoute** and
this will update the route url with dynamic query param here i.e. **manufacturer**

so inside ngOnInit you will get updated query param value like this

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        const manufacturer = params['manufacturer'];
        console.log('manufacturer',manufacturer);
      });
}
```

Let me know if this helps you, happy coding !!!

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't reload the page.